# Add Text & Excel table as picture to email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How do I add both text & Excel table (as a picture) to Outlook mail?

I don't want to use the `RangetoHTML1` function since it doesn't save the conditional formatting.

In the code below, the table is copied as picture to the mail. How do I add the text?

```
Sub SendCA_list()
    Dim oApp As Object, oMail As Object, rng As Range, p As Picture
    Dim strBody As String, wordDoc As Object

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set rng = Range("Table4[[#All],[Department]:[Status]]")
    rng.Copy  'copy required table
    Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste 'paste and cut the table to make picture
    p.Cut

    With oMail
        .Subject = "Request for CAs - ISO Audit"
        strBody = "<BODY style='font-size:12pt;font-family:HP Simplified'>" & _
            "Hi,<br><br>Please see attached report and the open " & _
            "AIs (itable below).<br><br>Best Regards,<br>Shira" & "</BODY>"
        .HTMLBody = strBody
        Set wordDoc = oMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        wordDoc.Range.Paste
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Here are several excellent examples of [**working with Outlook mail from Excel/VBA**](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm) from Ron deBruin.

Comment: Also, if the picture is working fine, it should not be included in the code or the question. (See [mcve])

Comment: thanks @ashleedawg, but i didn't find my request in the link above. The picture is indeed work find, but i wanna know if i'm doing wrong with the table pasting way and if that's why i can't see the text in the body...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is another way to approach the problem which exports the image and then attaches in with the HTML referring to the attached image.

```
Sub SendCA_list()

    Dim oApp As Object
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim oMail As Object
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("Table4[[#All],[Department]:[Status]]")
    rng.CopyPicture xlPrinter

    Dim chartObj As ChartObject
    Set chartObj = Sheet1.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, rng.Width, rng.Height)

    chartObj.Select
    chartObj.Chart.Paste
    chartObj.Chart.Export ThisWorkbook.Path & "\table.png", "png"
    chartObj.Delete

    Dim strbody As String
    strbody = "<BODY style='font-size:12pt;font-family:HP Simplified'>" & "Hi,<br><br>Please see attached the ISO Internal Audit Report and the open AIs (in the table below)."
    strbody = strbody & "<br><img src='cid:table.png'/>"
    strbody = strbody & "<br><br>Best Regards,<br>Shira<br><br></BODY>"

    With oMail

        .Subject = "Request for CAs - ISO Audit"
        .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\table.png", 1, 0
        .htmlbody = strbody
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code doesn't run. The error massage `Run time error 424 - object required` is appearing when stop on the code:  `Set chartObj = ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, rng.Width, rng.Height)`

Comment: Both the Range and ChartObject _should_ be qualified with the the code name of the worksheet where Table4 is located. In the example above I have added `Sheet1.` but you should change this to the code name of the sheet in your workbook.

Comment: ok, iv'e change the sheet name and now the code is running, but in the body the picture is apearing as error massage: 'The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may hve been moved, renamed ir deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location'

Comment: The code creates an image in the folder where the workbook is saved. Can you verify that this image exists and includes the correct table image?

Comment: Yes, the image is in the folder. But it doesn't be added to the body mail.

Comment: What version of Excel/Office are you using?
In the message, can you go to Format Text -> and confirm the Format is HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else could be causing this not to work as both of these methods work for me.

Comment: @DiederikSieburgh what is "Table4[[#All],[Department]:[Status]]"? 
Are they table header? I have Table1 in the range of A3 to J17.

Answer (score 0):

What is currently happening in your code is the Paste command of the picture is deleting the HTML already in body of the email. If you paste first and then amend the current HTMLbody (the image) to your String HTML you will get the desired results. Note: you may need to play around with this further to meet your exact needs of formatting the email.

**Edit:** I have included the full Sub now below. I have also added `.display` before appending your BODY string to the pasted image. Between testing and posting I had removed the `.display` but later realized this is needed to reference the `.htmlbody` value.

```
Sub SendCA_list()

    Dim oApp As Object
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim oMail As Object

    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("Table4[[#All],[Department]:[Status]]")
    rng.Copy  'copy required table

    Dim p As Picture
    Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste 'paste and cut the table to make it picture
    p.Cut

    Dim strbody As String

    With oMail

       .Subject = "Request for CAs - ISO Audit"
        strbody = "<BODY style='font-size:12pt;font-family:HP Simplified'>" & "Hi,<br><br>Please see attached the ISO Internal Audit Report and the open AIs (in the table below).<br><br>Best Regards,<br>Shira<br><br></BODY>"

        Dim wordDoc As Object
        Set wordDoc = oMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

        wordDoc.Range.Paste
        .Display
        .htmlbody = strbody & .htmlbody

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, but in this code only the text is appearing in the mail, and the table not appear.

Comment: Please your help o find a way to save both picture & text, thanks!

Comment: I edited this. Can you please let me know if it worked?

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't work.. In the mail body there is only the text